# Is there any equivalent ServiceDefinition.csdef for publish to an App service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, publish

We are updating a project that uses Azure tools to publish to a cloud service that will instead publish to an App service through Publish in visual studio 2017.

Through the Azure Tools we were able to define in .csdef VirtualApplicaton and VirtualDirectory to map the project as we wanted. But can not find anything to achieve this in order to publish to an app service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="Azure.Web.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="Azure.Web" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <VirtualDirectory name="backendprop" physicalDirectory="../../../PropertySystem/backendprop/">
          <VirtualApplication name="v1" physicalDirectory="../../../../Published/PropertySystem/Backend/v1/" />
          <VirtualApplication name="v1.1" physicalDirectory="../../../../Published/PropertySystem/Backend/v1.1/" />
          <VirtualApplication name="v1.2" physicalDirectory="../../../../Published/PropertySystem/Backend/v1.2/" />
        </VirtualDirectory>
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

We want to merge from the Published folder that is local and publish them in a new folder under backendprop like ServiceDefeniton.csdef which was used before.